# How to verify Admin dashboard and customer dashboard using of Selenium with JAVA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to verify Admin dashboard and customer dashboard using of Selenium with JAVA:

Admin Dashboard - for ex: there are 3 modules in admin (Dashboard, customer and Admin)
Customer Dashboard - for ex: there are 2 modules like (Dashboard and customer)

in that above scenario, if I login with customer and verifying Dashboard and Customer modules are available or not. IF I execute the script - It is verifying two modules, but how to validate admin module also there in the customer login - its a bug right. IF anyone know how to validate that using of selenium with java pls let me knw.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the user role with you have logged in

```
// Test for Customer Role
if (role == Customer) {

    // Get all the modules available to current logged-in role i.e. Customer

    List <WebElement> module = driver.findElements(By.id("xyz"));

    // check the how many modules present for customer
    if (module.size() == 2) {
        for (WebElement mod: module) {
            // if the count is 2 then will check if present modules have Admin one if yes, then will fail the test
            if (mod.getText() == "Admin") {
                System.out.println("Failed");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Pass");
            }
        }
    }
    // if 3 modules are present for Customer, then will directly fail the test
    else if(module.size() == 3) {
        System.out.println("Failed");
        Break;
    }
}
// Now check for Admin role
else {
    // Again will get the modules present for the Admin role
    List <WebElement> module1 = driver.findElements(By.id("xyz"));

    // check the module size if its 2 then we directly fail the test
    if (module1.size() == 2) {
        System.out.println("Failed");
        Break;
    }
    // if module size is 3
    else {
        for (WebElement mod1: module1) {
            // if the count is 3 then will check if all the 3 correct modules are present. 
            if (mod1.getText() == "Admin") {
                continue;
            } else if (mod1.getText() == "Customer") {
                continue;
            } else if ( mod1.getText() == "Dashboard") {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Test for Customer Role
if (role == Customer) {
    // Get all the modules available to current logged-in role i.e. Customer

    List <WebElement> module = driver.findElements(By.id("xyz"));

    // check the how many modules present for customer
    if (module.size() == 2) {
        for (WebElement mod: module) {
            //if the count is 2 then will check if present modules have Admin one if yes , then will fail the test
            if (mod.getText() == "Admin") {
                System.out.println("Failed");
                Break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Pass");
            } 
        } 
    }
    // if 3 modules are present for Customer, then will directly fail the test
    else if (module.size() == 3) {
        System.out.println("Failed");
        Break;
    }
}
// Now check for Admin role
else {
    // Again will get the modules present for the Admin role
    List <WebElement> module1 = driver.findElements(By.id("xyz"));

    // check the module size if its 2 then we directly fail the test
    if (module1.size() == 2){
        System.out.println("Failed");
        Break;
    }
    // if module size is 3
    else {
        for (WebElement mod1: module1) {
            // if the count is 3 then will check if all the 3 correct modules are present. 
            if (mod1.getText() == "Admin") {
                continue;
            } else if (mod1.getText() == "Customer") {
                continue;
            } else if (mod1.getText() == "Dashboard") {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example, currently, we have logged in with the Customer role and it has all 3 modules available (that is a negative scenario as per your requirement)
When we run the script - Test will terminate at `(Module.size()==3)`

Please check and let me know its work for you.

Comment: Probably you could improve your answer a bit since there seems to be a lot of code duplication.

Comment: Sure. Will improve